# Sublime plugin how to write text in the background (not interactable)

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to write a plugin that will show text that is not user-interactable. In other words, the text is part of the background--visible but does not affect the text on screen. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking (which I'm not sure I do), then no, this is not possible using the ST3 [public beta](http://www.sublimetext.com/3). You can set a view to be read-only using the `set_read_only()` method of [`sublime.View`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View), but that only disables editing of the view's contents - users can still select and copy any text present.

Alternatively, if you're using the ST3 [dev builds](http://www.sublimetext.com/3dev) and Build 3072 or later, you can use the new tooltip API to create a popup. It is my understanding (I haven't played around with it on all platforms yet) that text in a tooltip cannot be selected, at least on Windows.